# Fast Blur, Why is it so slow?

Tags: objective-c, performance, image-processing

Link 1)
http://blog.ivank.net/fastest-gaussian-blur.html#results

Link 2)
https://www.raywenderlich.com/69855/image-processing-in-ios-part-1-raw-bitmap-modification

Link 3)
https://github.com/tariqsebadi/fastBlur/blob/master/ImageProcessor.m

I'm pretty new to objective c, but I've tried to mix this tutorial from link 2, with algorithm four from link 1, ending up with link 3.  I was expecting to blur an image of decent quality under 100ms.  Yet the routine is far far slower than what I need, nearly 1 full second for 3 pass.  I need to hard code this because I
 want to implement it into an engine where speed/efficiency is priority.

Do I have the wrong approach? How can I make this much much faster?

TDLR: I need a super fast and efficient blur.  I'm trying, but the one I have is too slow. Help!

Comment: You'll need to use GPU acceleration to get decent performance.  Something like GPUImage might get you what you want, or you can do OpenGL shaders.

Comment: I've read GPUImage blur is slower than CoreImage from GPUImage github.  I've also considered Accelerate framework, but I'm not sure about its performance.  Do you have any links to get started with GPU acceleration?

Comment: I've had good results with two pass version discussed here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/07/15/an-investigation-of-fast-real-time-gpu-based-image-blur-algorithms, where one dimension is done with each pass with a 1-dim texture for the blur coefficients.  Haven't done it in iOS, though.